# Adding number to beginning of integer

Tags: c

I know that this may be a dumb question, but I am still learning C so I don't know all the nuances.

Basically the gist of my question is that say I have the separate integers 1, 3 and 2. I want to add 2 to 1 that makes it 21. I know I could do 2*10, then add 1. Then add 3 to the beginning making it 321. Basically I need to add one number to the beginning of another number multiple times. Sadly, I cannot use the pow function for this.

Let me know if you need me to explain it anymore.

Comment: You can convert to digits to strings and concatenate them. (Probably not the best way, performance-wise)

Comment: Have a look at `sprintf()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: Re "*Sadly, I cannot use the pow function for this.*", So use multiplication like you showed

Comment: Using the `pow()` function wouldn't be a particularly good idea — use multiplication.  You should show what you've tried.  Do you get all the digits to be added (effectively starting from 0), or could you be given a number such as 34567 and then have to add `9`, `0`, `1` in turn to the start.  Is the result of that 10934567 or 1934567?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). It is important to show your best effort to date, and explain what isn't working.  SO is not a coding service.  We like to see an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.  At the least, you need to show example inputs and the expected output.  You say you are given 1, 3, 2 — yet you decide to put 2 in front of 1 and then 3. Why? Did you sort something?

Comment: `"I know I could do 2*10, then add 1."` -- It seems that you have already figured out the solution to your problem. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" site. It is a site for asking specific programming questions. Therefore, please describe in detail what problem you encountered in your attempt of solving the problem yourself, and please show us any code that you may have already written in your attempt. You may want to read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Comment: Note that you do not need the `pow` function to multiply a number multiple times by `10`.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways you can do this.

If you can't use the pow function why not make your own?

Here is one way I thought of doing this. I hope this can inspire you to come up with your own way.

If you need more then 10 digits you would have to use long instead of int.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int notpow(int y) {
    int ans = 10;
    if (y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < y; i++) {
        ans *= 10;
    }
    return ans;
}


int main() {
    // //Basic idea
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 3;
    int num3 = 2;
    int ans = 0;
    ans = num1*notpow(2) + num2 *notpow(1) + num3*notpow(0);
    printf("ans = %i\n", ans);
    //For n numbers
    int howMany, howManyCount = 1;
    printf("How many digits?: ");
    scanf("%d",&howMany);
    int temp = 0;
    int countDown = howMany-1;
    ans = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        printf("Enter digit %i: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        printf("\n");
        ans = ans + temp*notpow(countDown--);
        printf("ans = %i\n", ans);
    }
    printf("Final ans = %i\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can try out this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int power(int base, int exp) {
    int res = 1;
    while (exp > 0) {
        res *= base;
        exp--;
    }

    return res;
}

int main() {
    int someNumber = 7, length, numToAdd = 3;
    char string[10];
    sprintf(string, "%d", someNumber);
    length = strlen(string);
    someNumber = numToAdd * power(10, length) + someNumber;
    printf("%d\n", someNumber);
}
```

I hope the code is self explanatory.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. However, at the time of this writing, two other people did. My guess is that they did not consider it helpful to simply provide the solution to a homework question (without even explaining it). You may want to read these community guidelines on homework questions: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)